# Summing every third column if its adjacent column has substring with formulas

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

So I have rows which are filled with an unknown number of entries, which are all composed of an ID, a name and an amount.

I have managed to sum every third cell starting on the seventh column using the following formula:

```
=SUMIF(ARRAYFORMULA(MOD((COLUMN(A6:6)-COLUMN(A6)+6),3)),0,A6:6)
```

Now I would like to find a way to only add cells where the corresponding ID contains an "INV" tag, but I have not been able to figure it out myself.

[image: What the sheet looks like]

Comment: There is a much simpler way to get at what you're after.  If you share an editable sample sheet it can be tested and demonstrated.

Comment: What's wrong with just `=SUM(6:6)`?

Comment: [Editable sample sheet here!](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1nnQ_cJ6GHngbcdm-sCAH_-Y3TuyrVE_45J3ccPm4P7A/edit?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Easiest way is to just call

  ```
  =SUM(E2:2)
  ```

  This  will ignore all text, but it's not specific to  `INV` tags. Then you can simply drag fill down.
- To be specific for `INV` tags,

  ```
  =ARRAYFORMULA(MMULT(IF(REGEXMATCH(""&E2:M13,"^INV"),G2:M13,0),SEQUENCE(COLUMNS(E2:M13),1,1,)))
  ```

  - `IF`  with offsetted/differential array arguments:

    - Condition array starting with E2
    - Result array starting with G2
  - `REGEXMATCH` to test for `INV` tag
  - `MMULT` to matrix multiply to get array sum
  - `SEQUENCE` to create a 1D ones array to provide a second argument to `MMULT` to get array sum

Answer (score 0):

> Summing every third column if its adjacent column has substring

try:

```
=INDEX(MMULT(IF(FILTER(G2:13, MOD(COLUMN(G1:1)-2, 3)=0)="", 0, 
 FILTER(G2:13, MOD(COLUMN(G1:1)-1, 3)=0)), 
 SEQUENCE(COLUMNS(FILTER(G2:13, MOD(COLUMN(G1:1)-2, 3)=0)))^0))
```

[image]

for just INV tags use:

```
=INDEX(MMULT(IF(REGEXMATCH(FILTER(G2:13, MOD(COLUMN(G1:1)-2, 3)=0), "INV.*"), 
 FILTER(G2:13, MOD(COLUMN(G1:1)-1, 3)=0), 0), 
 SEQUENCE(COLUMNS(FILTER(G2:13, MOD(COLUMN(G1:1)-2, 3)=0)))^0))
```

[image]

Comment: @MathieuBuchs answer updated